# Python timers with no threading

Tags: python, flask-socketio

I have a Python flask-socketio server, and I want to sync a timer to the clients. I tried doing the timer in the client, but it doesn't sync reliably, so I decided I need to do the timer on the server. The problem is Threading requires a lot of expensive processing from the server, and I don't want to deal with eventlet, gevent, or the standard threading. Is there a way to sync a timer reliably without threading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by *"Threading requires a lot of expensive processing"*, but in any case, threading is incompatible with eventlet and with gevent, so it wouldn't work anyway.

Gevent and eventlet both provide a replacement module that implements everything in threading using greenlets. For example, you can import the `Timer` class from eventlet with:

```
from eventlet.green.threading import Timer
```

As far as accuracy I'm not sure what your expectations are. Since greenlets are cooperative, exact timers are not possible, so in general the timeouts that you specify are a minimum, so the timer may fire a bit later than the requested time depending on how other tasks cooperate with the async loop.